# How can I mock properties which have no setters in unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to do unit testing for my universal app and am looking for a way to test a function that uses the `Geocoordinate` class.

Let's say you have the following function (which contains a lot more logic in my case, of course):

```
public int GetAccuracy(Geocoordinate coord) {
    return coord.Accuracy;
}
```

How can I unit test it? I can create a `Geocoordinate` object but I can't set an `Accuracy` in my unit test method. `Accuracy` and other properties like the latitude and longituge only have a getter.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: are you using a mocking framework, eg. Moq?

Comment: Not yet, as I am just about to learn how unit testing works for WP/Win app (just unit tests java coded yet) but I am open to start using it if it solves this special problem. ;)

Comment: What geolocation library are you talking about? There's no `Accuracy` property on the [System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and both the `HorizontalAccuracy` and `VerticalAccuracy` properties have public setters as well as getters.

Comment: First of all, moq doesn't seem to support WinRT in general :/ Secondly [Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geocoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.aspx) is what I am using. Ask MS why they just used a lower case 'c' ;)

Comment: For testing situations like this, I find Moq is so useful that it is worth putting all you can into a PCL, then you can test it using a normal (i.e NOT windows store) assembly with Nunit, Moq, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I try to also unit test IValueConverters where I convert coordinates to the properties I need. Putting them into a PCL would be an overkill in my eyes. Seems like I can't unit test that small part of my app with available tools :/

Comment: I wonder if you can use reflection to set the values. Maybe serializing/deserializing with JSON.NET can do this automatically? Worth a try.

Comment: So after doing some research, it seems that the best answer is likely to create your own coordinate class, then fill it with the content from the runtime class. This way your mocking works just fine, you have detailed control over serialization (if that's desired), and your code is more portable. You can also make an implicit conversion from the platform geoocordinate to your custom one if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own abstract interface for Geocoordinate, and pass an instance of the interface to the GetAccuracy method. Your app would use an implementation that simply wraps a Geocoordinate instance, whilst your unit test would create a mocked version of the interface.